# dividing col-md-2 again in to halves doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to divide a `col-md-4` again in to a `col-md-6` and `col-md-6` and its not working what i was expecting was to get the two `col-md-6`s in the the same line .but i am getting the second `col-md-6` beneath the `first col-md-6`.

Here is my HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-md-2
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:red;">
        red
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:green;">
        green
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/qfoLe5vu/32/) is the fiddle illustrating the issue.Please update what has gone wrong or if this should be attained in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.row` class, try this:

```
 <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-md-2
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:red;">
             red
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:green;">
             green
         </div>
     </div> </div>
```

Have a look at this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) for more information

Answer (score 3):

For the bootstrap grid system to work properly, the format should be `row > col + col`. In your code, you don't have any elements with a `row` class.

Bootstrap also has predefined classes for extra-small devices, small-devices, large-devices and you should use them appropriately depending upon what you want.

Read more about Bootstrap grid system [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system) to understand it better.

Hence, this should work :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

    <div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
            red
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:green;">
            green
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take note of `col-md-6`, `col-sm-6` etc. They all define how these divs will look on different devices. Check out this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) demo on the official  Bootstrap site. For quick reference in the future, I am leaving this screenshot here (which explains these classes) :

[image]

Here is your updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfoLe5vu/36/)**

Answer (score 2):

you need to put a div class="row" inside the div class="col-md-1"

```
 <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-md-2
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:red;">
         red
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:green;">
         green
     </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong then do you want this ? [Click to see](http://jsfiddle.net/qfoLe5vu/35/)

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:red; float:right">
        red
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:green; float:right">
        green
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```